# Gas Fireplace how to insulate for constant draft

Tags: insulation, gas, fireplace

We have a gas fireplace that the contractor did not insulate and causes a constant breeze through the bottom vent.  Would it be safe to line the bottom walls with mineral wool?

The air is continuous which will is both costly in the Winter and Summer.  I am posting in hopes to get contractors to help with the best solution.

Comment: not 100% sure what you're asking, but you don't want to block any airflow, and if you don't block airflow, what's the point of insulating?

Comment: The bottom has a vent, but there it is is a trapezoid shape that houses the gas line for turning on the gas fireplace.  However, there are holes that let in a tremendous amount of airflow.